# How to use with open to filter datafiles in python and create new file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, bigdata, data-warehouse

i have huge csv and i tried to filter data using with open.

I know i can use FINDSTR on command line but i would like to use python to create a new file filtered or i would like to create a  pandas dataframe as output.

here is my code:

```
outfile = open('my_file2.csv', 'a')
with open('my_file1.csv', 'r') as f:
 for lines in f:
         if '31/10/2018' in lines:
            print(lines)  
         outfile.write(lines)
```

The problem is that the output file generated is = input file and there is no filter(and the size of file is the same)

Thanks to all

Comment: Close to a typo: you just have to indent  `outfile.write(lines)` the same as `print(lines)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is the indentation of the last line. It should be within the if-statement, so only lines that contain `'31/10/2018'` get written.

```
outfile = open('my_file2.csv', 'a')
with open('my_file1.csv', 'r') as f:
 for lines in f:
         if '31/10/2018' in lines:
            print(lines)  
            outfile.write(lines)
```

To filter using Pandas and creating a DataFrame, do something along the lines of:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

# I assume here that the date is in a seperate column, named 'Date'
df = pd.read_csv('my_file1.csv', parse_dates=['Date']) 

# Filter on October 31st 2018
df_filter = df[df['Date'].dt.date == datetime.date(2018, 10, 31)]

# Output to csv
df_filter.to_csv('my_file2.csv', index=False)
```

(For very large csv's, look at the `pd.read_csv()` argument 'chunksize')

To use `with open(....) as f:`, you could do something like:

```
import pandas as pd

filtered_list = []
with open('my_file1.csv', 'r') as f:
    for lines in f:
        if '31/10/2018' in lines:
            print(lines)
            # Split line by comma into list
            line_data = lines.split(',')
            filtered_list.append(line_data)

# Convert to dataframe and export as csv
df = pd.DataFrame(filtered_list)
df_filter.to_csv('my_file2.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: thanks. Do you know how can i use the filtered data in a pandas dataframe without create a new file? or how can i filter data by column with my code?

Comment: ok thanks but i mean the output of: with open('my_file1.csv', 'r') as f:
 for lines in f:
         if '31/10/2018' in lines:
            print(lines)

Comment: Why would you want to do that, if you are going to use Pandas anyway? Or does `'my_file1.csv'` also contain other lines besides a header and data rows?

Comment: because the file is too large, i wuold like to analyze only the output obtained with print(lines). and i dont know why but the output file(my_file2.csv) missing 10 row

Comment: See the solution above